# how can i get the correct access to github so i can push repo's?

Tags: git, git-push

when i try to push something form local git to github this happens & i don't know how to solve that .

---

warning :permanently added the RSA host key for ip addres '......' to the list of known hosts
permission denied (publickey)
fatal:could not read from remote repository
please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repo exits

---

knowing that i used this commands before that happens
Mkdir ~/Name
cd ~/Name
git init
git remote add orgin
git remote add orgin git@github.com:Myacc
touch file
git add .
git commit -m "add Name"
git push orgin master (Error happend )
git pull orgin master
git push orgin master

So what should i do ?

Comment: Did you try to restart the console?

Comment: can you post screenshot ? so that it is easy to understand situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the username that SSH should send to the remote system as part of your remote's URL. Put the username, followed by an @, before the remote hostname.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this problem. But one very common reason can be public key is not set on your git shell.

Try following steps to check your SSH public key.

1. run this command on your terminal:

   ssh-agent -s

   ssh-add -l
2. Now open github.com and login your account. you will see SSH keys in settings option. compare that SSH key with the key generated by above command.

for other reasons you can see git help here : https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Thanks,

Bhavik

Comment: Thanks , but i can't get it , i used the both commands but no keys appear so how can i compare them , before i generated a key and put it in the ssh key at github after that when i trying to push the file its rejected

Comment: That is what appear after i use git push command

Username for 'https://github.com': Asizux
Password for 'https://Asizux@github.com':
To https://github.com/Asizux/datasciencecoursera.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Asizux/datascienceco
a.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behin
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: According to your this error "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind", you may have rebase your local commits. For that try using "git push <remote> --force" command. And use it very carefully. Because it will push the commits forcefully (non-fast-forward).